# Simultaneously call asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation, jsom

Is there any best practice how to execute an asynchronous function multiple times (JavaScript, SharePoint, JSOM)? Think of this scenario:

```
// simplified
function MultipleExec() 
{
   var a = GetListData('ListA');
   var b = GetListData('ListB');
   var c = GetListData('ListC');
}

function GetListData(listName) 
{
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var spList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
   [..]
   context.load(listItems);

   context.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args) 
   {
      var listItemsEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
      var data = '';

      while (listItemsEnumerator.moveNext()) 
      {
         var listItem = listItemsEnumerator.get_current();
         data += listItem.get_item('Title') + '\n'
      }

      return data;    
   }
}
```

Promises? How should promises be implemented? And what if I dont want my code do act synchronously? Is it even good practice to reuse code like this or should I think completely different?

Comment: Do you have jQuery available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync calls are not good pratices and are not allowed by modern browsers anyway.

Here you have two options:

1. Parallel calls (so all the requests will be done at the same time)
2. Or one by one call

In both cases I recommend using Promise (with [polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill)).

For the first case, the parallel calls:

```
function MultipleExec() 
{
  Promise.all([
    GetListData('ListA'),
    GetListData('ListB'),
    GetListData('ListC')
  ]).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results[0]) // data from ListA
    console.log(results[1]) // data from ListB
    console.log(results[2]) // data from ListC
  })
}
```

In the second case (one call after the other one):

```
function MultipleExec() 
{
  var dfd = Promise.resolve();
  var res = ["ListA", "ListB", "ListC"].map(function(list) {
    dfd = dfd.then(function() {
      return GetListData(list);
    });
    return dfd
  });
  Promise.all(res).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results[0]) // data from ListA
    console.log(results[1]) // data from ListB
    console.log(results[2]) // data from ListC
  })
}
```

And for both of them the `GetListData` will look like that:

```
function GetListData(listName)
{
  return new Promise(function(prom_res, prom_rej) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var spList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    [..]
    context.load(listItems);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args)
    {
       var listItemsEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
       var data = '';

       while (listItemsEnumerator.moveNext())
       {
          var listItem = listItemsEnumerator.get_current();
          data += listItem.get_item('Title') + '\n'
       }

       prom_res(data);
    }
  })
}
```